# Find parameter of inequality

Tags: inequality

Find the parameter $m \in \mathbb R$ so that  $$x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2 + 2x - 6y + m \ge 0, \forall x, y \in \mathbb R$$

I tried forming some squares but it seems it doesn't help me

$$(x-y)^2 + y^2 + 2x -6y + m \ge 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y^2+x^2+1+2x-2y-2xy=(y-x-1)^2$ and $y^2-4y+4=(y-2)^2$. Total of these, we yields

$$x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2 + 2x - 6y + m = (y-x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + m - 5 \geq 0$$

Hence, we find that $ m\geq 5$.

Comment: Could you give me a sort of an algorithm to form those squares ? I would have never thought to rewrite like that.

Comment: I hope that this is useful for you:

$2y^2 = y^2 + y^2$. (We have two $y^2$'s but only one $x^2$). Hence I have to seach $(y-x+a)^2+(y+b)^2$. I have to effort on the expression $(y-x+a)^2+(y+b)^2$ and finding $a,b$ numbers.